# Reordering the test cases in a FitNesse test suite

Tags: fitnesse

I have a test suite with tests ordered as:

```
Suite1---A
         B
         C
```

How can I change the order of the test cases?

I have tried refactoring but that is not helping.

Comment: Yes I have tried specifying the sub pages manually in content.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look this is possible...

> Remember, that the order tests run is alphabetical. So in the above example, TestThree will not run because TestTwo actually comes after TestThree
>
> --[FitNesse > UserGuide > TestSuites > TagsAndFilters](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.TestSuites.TagsAndFilters)

...but it shouldn't matter. Tests should be independent and not rely upon previous tests (other than [**`SuiteSetUp`**](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.TestSuites.SuiteSetUpAndSuiteTearDown)).

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. So can you please let me know how to specify SetUp and TearDown for suite. I have gone through [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997388/fitnesse-how-to-initialize-teardown-suite-not-individual-test) but I really need some examples.

Comment: I think I will try SuiteSetUp and SuiteTearDown and let you know

Comment: Okay now I have moved all the set up information to SuiteSetUp and SuiteTearDown and its running correctly. Thanks again for your response.

Comment: @kshitij-gupta: Glad to have helped. [Please remember to mark the most useful answer as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).